# i installed numpy 1.26.3 but still not able to use np. method

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, np, numpy-ufunc

I installed NUMPY by using pip install NUMPY
and it installed and then I'm still not able to use
np. method .
the NUMPY version is 1.26.3.
the error in "np is not defined".
can somebody pleas help me with installing NUMPY.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to run?

Comment: a = np.array([[2],[1],[3]])

Answer (score 1):

Add `import numpy as np` to the beginning.of your .py file.

If doing so gives you an ImportError, then install numpy with `python -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied" it says

Comment: sht it worked      tnx a lot man  appreciate you